# Comparing factorials (From greatest to least)

Tags: factorial, sorting

Let's say we're asked to arrange these factorials in descending order: $1000!, \,\,700!\cdot300!,\,\,500!\cdot500!,\,\,600!\cdot300!\cdot100!$

For the first three, we could do:

$\dbinom{1000}{300}>1 \Rightarrow 1000!>700!\cdot300!$

$\dbinom{1000}{500}>\dbinom{1000}{300} \Rightarrow 700! \cdot 300! > 500! \cdot 500!$

However I don't know how to approach the fourth one, i.e how do we prove that $500!\cdot500!>600!\cdot300!\cdot100!$ ?

Answer (score 1):

What is 
$$
\frac{(a+b+c)!} {a! \,b! \,c!}
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate?